# Celery task is hanging with http request

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm testing celery tasks and have stumbled on issue. If in task exists code with request(through urllib.urlopen) then it's hanging. What reasons can be?

I just try start on minimal config with Flask.
I used rabbitmq and redis for broker and backend, but result is the same.

file(run_celery.py) with tasks:

```
...import celery and flask app...

celery = Celery(
    app.import_name,
    backend=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],
    broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
)

@celery.task
def test_task(a):
    print(a)
    print(requests.get('http://google.com'))
```

In this way I launched worker:
celery -A run_celery.celery worker -l debug

After this, I run ipython and call task.

```
from run_celery import test_task
test_task.apply_async(('sfas',))
```

Worker's beginning perform task:

```
...
Received task: run_celery.test_task...
sfas
Starting new HTTP connection (1)...
```

And after this it's hanging.

This behavior is actual only if task contain request.
What Did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the status of your task in redis?  What happens if you add a timeout to the request?

Comment: @bwarren2
Nothing. Python must to raise exception, if I set timeout for urlopen, but nothing happened. It looks like celery task is hanging.

Comment: @bwarren2
When task is performing and hanging, within redis exists only 3 keys:
`127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "_kombu.binding.celeryev"
2) "_kombu.binding.celery.pidbox"
3) "_kombu.binding.celery"`

Comment: A few more things to try: what happens if you set a (short) task time limit? What about BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 10}  # 10s. ?  It is not clear to me where the problem is yet, so more tweaking might be informative.

Comment: @bwarren2 Thanks for your time. I found reason, but need to it more explore.

Answer (score 0):

I found reason in my code and very wondered O_o. I don't know why this is happening but within file with tasks, exists import Model and when it is executing then perform initialization instance MagentoAPI(https://github.com/bernieke/python-magento). If I comment out this initialization then requests in celery tasks perform correctly.